# Access variable hash depth values with square brackets notation

Tags: ruby, hash

Given this hash:

```
hash1= { node1: { node2: { node3: { node4: { node5: 1 } } } } }
```

We access inside nodes with square brackets like this:

```
hash1[:node1][:node2][:node3][:node4]
```

Now I have a hash that I know will always be nested as it is an XML response from a SOAP webservice, but neither the depth of the hash nor the names of the nodes stay the same. So it would be nice if I could ask the user of my application for the hash depth and store it in a variable. And then be able to do `hash1[:hash_depth]` and achieve the same result as above.

I have accomplished what I want by the following code:

```
str = 'node1,node2,node3,node4'
str_a = str.split(',')
hash_copy = hash1
str_a.each { |s| hash_copy = hash_copy.[](s.to_sym) }
hash_copy
=> {:node5=>1}
hash1[:node1][:node2][:node3][:node4]
=> {:node5=>1}
```

that is asking the user to enter the hash depth separated by commas, store it in a string, split it, make an array, clone the original hash, go down each level and modify the hash till I get to the desired node. Is there a way to do it with the square brackets notation and using a variable to store the depth without modifying the hash or needing to clone it?

**Edit**:
someone answered with the following (can't see his post anymore???)

```
hash_depth="[:node1][:node2][:node3][:node4]"
eval "hash1#{hash_depth}"
```

Comment: It is ungrammatical to use `nor` in affirmative sentences like "the depth of the hash nor the names of the nodes stay the same". Did you mean they do **not** stay the same, in other words, **neither** of them stay the same?

Comment: @sawa sorry english is not my first language. I edited my post adding neither, hope it makes sense now and is grammatically correct too? if not correct me please.

Comment: Your edit made that part okay. Your wording "hash depth" is misleading. You seem to mean "a sequence of hash keys".

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer if you find any of them helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Although `eval` does everything you need, there is another approach, since you already have the working code for comma-separated list:

```
hash_depth="[:node1][:node2][:node3][:node4]"
csh = hash_depth.gsub(/\A\[:|\]\[:|\]\Z/, { '][:' => ',' })
#⇒ "node1,node2,node3,node4"
```

And now you are free to apply your existing function to `csh`.

Comment: This is not what I asked for, but it will be useful if I want the user to input the hash_depth in a ruby square bracket notation, instead of just the names of the nodes separated by commas. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If this is a webapp, I think you should prepare a list of short textareas, which starts with a single text item, and the user can keep adding a new item to the list by clicking on a button. The areas will be filled by the user, and will be sent.

Then, you will probably receive this through some serialized form. You decode this to get an array of strings:

```
str_a = ["node1", "node2", "node3", "node4"]
```

and you can reach the inner element by doing:

```
str_a.inject(hash1){|h, s| h[s.to_sym]} #=> {:node5 => 1}
```

Comment: Do you think this answer can be improved with `Hash#dig`?